# How to add CNAME for subdomain to a separate hosted zone in AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I want to set up a separate hosted zone for a subdomain in Route53 as discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/817651/can-different-aws-accounts-manage-different-subdomains/817807).

The subdomain hosted zone (subdomain.domain.com) is in a different AWS account than the hosted zone for the domain (domain.com).
I also want a CNAME for the subdomain that points to an ALB listener. Now I can create the subdomain hosted zone, but creating the CNAME fails due to a name conflict:

```
Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name subdomain.domain.com. is not permitted as it conflicts with other records with the same DNS name in zone subdomain.domain.com.]
        status code: 400, request id: somethingsomething
```

The NS and SOA records have the same DNS name as the CNAME I want to add. Would I have to name the subdomain something else? If yes, what would be appropriate?

Comment: is ALB in parent AWS account or subdomain AWS account?

Comment: @DusanBajic, in same account as subdomain

Comment: Then you should just (in subdomain zone) create ALIAS record instead of CNAME record.

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic, that worked! Feel free to post an answer which I could upvote and accept.